# Use of unresolved identifier false warning Swift 3 xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swift3

So I edited my post to be more clear. I am new in xcode and Swift 3 and I am facing to a strange problem. My project contains several swift files. I put all my simple common methods to Utils.swift, for instance simple string functions, etc. For many days I had no problems but after a point xcode is all the time complaining with red exclamation marks in all the files where I use my method if I am calling my methods from Utils.swift file: "Use of unresolved identifier 'xxx'".

```
// debug is a bool variable declared before
```

Utils.swift:

```
func log(_ message: String) {
    if debug {
        print(message)
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
log("Error happened")
```

This gives an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'Log' ". Obviously the function is there so I don't understand why I get this red warning with exclamation mark during coding however when I click on Build, it is successful, and it runs perfectly and the warning is gone. As soon as I start typing again in the code area, the red error comes back. If I build it once more it is successful again. It doesn't make any sense to me.

I thought it is maybe a cache problem, xcode live issues function doesn't recognise my Utils.swift or something like this... so I cleaned the build folder (cmd + shift + option + K), I cleaned the project (Product > Clean), restarted xcode, restarted Mac, removed Utils.swift, re-added Utils.swift to the project but can not get rid of these false warnings during coding but if build the project it is OK. I don't have this problem in my other projects. Any idea?

Comment: I think it is not about the code as I described the problem in my post. The code builds perfectly. It must be some setting or... I don't know. But for the request I updated my question with the code. This gives an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'Log' ". Obviously the function is there so I don't understand why I get this red warning with exclamation mark during coding however when I click on Build, it is successful, and it runs perfectly. As soon as I start typing again in the code, the red errors come back.

Comment: What's the name of your module (app)? Try namespacing your `log` call. For example, if your app is called MyApp, say `MyApp.Log("Error happened")` or `MyApp.log("Error happened")` or whatever.

Comment: Also if you can make a reproducible example, send it on in as a bug report to Apple, please.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I found the answer myself. Clicking on the swift file (now Utils.swift) I had to select "Location Relative to Group" in file inspector and set the appropriate target memberships as well.

It is weird that despite the previous 'wrong' settings the build completes with success however it gives an error in the code area.